# Conditional Formatting with Date Formulas and Checkboxes

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am wanting to establish a conditional format based on a checkbox and the difference in time. Column A is "Test", Column B is "Start Time", and Column C is "End Time." If Column A's box is checked (patient got tested), then their end time will be different than if they were not tested. The end time is conditional on the start time.

So, I have tried a few different equations with the IF function, which typically goes:
=IF (logical expression, value if true, value if false)
My attempt:
=IF(A1=TRUE, C1=B1+120/24, C1=B1+132/24)
I know the IF function is sensitive with dates, so this has brought on the issue.

Any advice or suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: share a copy/sample of your sheet with example of desired output

Comment: I also suggest that you share a sample sheet with your expected output. [Share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383). I did not fully understood your goal.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=IF(A1=TRUE, B1+120/24, B1+132/24)
```